# Split a file into smaller once of different lengths in unix

Tags: bash, shell, file, unix, split

I have a big file of 11GB and I am doing some operation on the contents. Due to limitations in storage capacity of account I had to split the file into smaller once. Out of the many operation I do there is a duplicate removal. I am spliting the file into 4L records each. The problem lies when a duplicate record falls into 2 different file because of spliting. This was when I finally merge all the files It still has some duplicates.
For Example file big.txt has

```
aa
bb
cc
cc
dd
dd
ee
ff
ff
hh
```

If I split into smaller once of l=5 each. I will have 2 files

aa.txt containing

```
aa
bb
cc
cc
dd
```

ab.txt containing

```
dd
ee
ff
ff
hh
```

On removong duplicates from aa.txt and ab.txt I will have

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

and

```
dd
ee
ff
hh
```

No as I merge then I will have

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
dd
ee
ff
hh
```

So duplicate record for dd still exists. Its was because they fell into 2 diffrent files.

Comment: I see your `big.txt` is sorted.  Is there some reason not to do duplicate removal first?  Try: `uniq big.txt | split -l 5`

Comment: In my actual scenario its not sorted. Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will return only unique lines without having to sort.

`perl -ne 'print unless $seen{$_}++' big.txt`

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/how-to-get-only-the-unique-results-without-having-to-sort-data for more information.

Comment: Runing this on the whole file which had almost 52L records hanged the system. It was the reason I wanted to split process and merge